# Wikipedia Query Filter Ancestor Categories

Tags: json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Sending request:

```
{
        "action": "query",
        "format": "json",
        "prop": "categories",
        "titles": "Barry Archbold",
        "redirects": 1,
        "utf8": 1,
        "formatversion": "2",
        "clcategories": "Category:Living people"  //one of this page's category
}
```

returns response:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 40902107,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Barry Archbold",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Living people"
                    }]...
```

but if I change `clcategories` to `Category:Life` which is one of the parent categories of `Category:Living people` according to [Wiki's Category Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CategoryTree?target=Category%3ALiving%20people&mode=all&namespaces=0&title=Special%3ACategoryTree), the `categories` array won't show in the response:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 40902107,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Barry Archbold"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to filter the response by **ancestor category** when **query by titles**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&titles=Barry%20Archbold&redirects=1&clcategories=Category:Living%20people to save others the effort. Can you clarify exactly what response you are expecting? Are you looking to get all of the parent categories for Barry Archold? Fairly sure you'll need to make separate calls to do that as there is no direct link from there to Category:Life

Comment: @smartse I want to get or filter by the parent category with in the same response if it’s possible.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that's not possible in the same call. You'll need do https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&titles=Category:Living%20people&redirects=1&clprop=hidden seperately.

Comment: @smartse I think you are right. After I dig wiki's API, I think there have to be two API calls. According to the wiki's database schema, the information I need is located in three tables, I guess multiple actions are required.